# How to use FunctionCompile and Compile as external definition?

Tags: compile, external-calls, function-compile, nested-function

Let's consider the following functions (in `$Version`: 12.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021))

```
f1=Compile[{{arg,_Integer}},Module[{output=0},output+=arg*10;output],CompilationTarget->"C"];
f2=FunctionCompile[Function[{Typed[arg,"Integer64"]},Module[{output=0},output+=arg*10;output]]];
f3=FunctionCompile[Function[{Typed[arg,TypeSpecifier["NumericArray"]["Integer64",1]]}, 
    Module[{output=0},output+=Length[arg]*10;output]]];
```

I want write new functions with above functions as external definitions (as below)

```
g1=FunctionCompile[Function[{Typed[arg,"Integer64"]},Module[{output=0},output+=f1[arg]*10;output]]];
g2=FunctionCompile[Function[{Typed[arg,"Integer64"]},Module[{output=0},output+=f2[arg]*10;output]]];
g3=Compile[{{arg,_Integer,1}},Module[{arg1,output=0},arg1=NumericArray[arg,"Integer64"]; 
    output+=f3[arg1]*10;output],CompilationTarget->"C"];
```

The `g` functions are giving compilation error

```
Compile::err: TypeError. Cannot find a definition for the function CompiledFunction[Argument count: 1
Argument types: {_Integer}

] that takes an argument with the type Integer64.

Compile::err: TypeError. Cannot find a definition for the function CompiledCodeFunction[Signature: {Integer64}->Integer64] that takes an argument with the type Integer64.

Compile::cset: Variable output of type {_Integer,0} encountered in assignment of type {_Integer,1}.

Compile::cset: Variable output of type {_Integer,0} encountered in assignment of type {_Integer,1}.
```

However, the following function, is working fine.

```
g4=Compile[{{arg,_Integer}},Module[{output=0},output+=f2[arg]*10;output],CompilationTarget->"C"];
```

Could anyone let me know if there is any particular way, this (external call) could be achieved?

Comment: If you guarantee that `f1` and `f2` are present in the kernel when you evaluate `g1` and `g2` respectively, you can use [`KernelFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KernelFunction.html).